# Как сделать адаптивный фон с возможность менять картинку в html?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть адаптивный фон в CSS, но нужно чтобы ссылку на картинку можно было прописывать не в стилях а в коде. Как это сделать?

```
.vid {
background-image: url('/img/bg.jpg');
background-position: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
}
```

Comment: А что, если менять background-image скриптом?

Comment: А как это реализовать?
Я пока только к такому пришел: <div style="background-image: url('/img/bg.jpg');"></div> .

Comment: Что значит "адаптивный фон"? При каких условиях вы хотите менять этот фон?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/zLhv43mo/

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обратиться к своим элементам по селектору `.vid` :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.vid');
```

А затем поменять всем этим элементам фон в цикле:

```
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundImage = '/img/bg2.jpg';
}
```

Или так:

```
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = '/img/bg2.jpg';
});
```